# Problem running jupyter notebook from AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

While I execute: `~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook`

```
[W 20:12:31.012 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 8 ('127.0.0.1', 44788): [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:645)
[W 20:12:31.013 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('127.0.0.1', 44790): [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:645)
[W 20:12:31.626 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 10 ('127.0.0.1', 44792): [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:645)
[W 20:12:33.520 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 8 ('127.0.0.1', 44800): [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:645)
[W 20:12:33.520

[W 20:13:00.995 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 20:13:00.996 NotebookApp] Kernel b09e557c-561f-4ba2-b3d7-939dfde14282 died, removing from map.

channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

And this is what appears to me on the **jupyter** notebook when I try to run something on the **python3**

```
Connection failed
A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.
```

I created the `SSL` this way:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mykey.key -out mycert.pem -sha256
```

How can I fix this mistake?

My PC is a MAC, in AWS I have installed a Linux.
I am using Google Chrome Version 80.0.3987.163

Comment: Could you tunnel notebook to your localhost using ssh? This the least painful way of accessing a notebook on localhost which is hosted on a remote server.

Comment: Yes, I actually do that and I get to the notebook. 
The problem is the SSL Error and the connection refused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From issue [6396](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6396) of jupyterlab:

*This might be some extra protection Chrome is attempting to provide, especially if it works well in other browsers. I think Chrome has upped its security precautions with self-signed certificates over the years.*

You first could try to use another browser like Safari and the problem could go away. Another method would be changing the settings for self signed certificates in Chrome as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate).

Comment: Good answer, I'll try that solution. Thank you very much.